# Random phases of Hamiltonian eigenstates

Tags: quantum-mechanics

A random question struck my mind. If $|\phi_n\rangle$ be an eigenstate of Hamiltonian H (s.t. $H |\phi_n\rangle =E_n|\phi_n\rangle$), so is $e^{i\delta_n}|\phi_n\rangle$ for any real $\delta_n$. This is true for any n. These phases aren't global but relative, as they depend on $n$. Would these ambiguous phases that could be attached to eigenstates be problematic while making predictions using these states?

Answer (score 1):

No. Such arbitrary phase choices make no difference. Physical quantities are derived from probabilities that are computed from the magnitude of squares of matrix elements
$$
|\langle n|O|m\rangle|^2 
$$
and these are unaffected by the  phases.  Phase choices do get involved in the *formalism* sometimes. For example in the adiabatic theorem  the "Berry phase" depends on the phase choices. But again,  when one computes a physical quantity, the phases drop out in the end.

Comment: Should it not be the Berry *connection* which depends on the phase choices, with the Berry phase being left invariant under such changes?

Comment: @J. Murray. Yes. You are correct!